# Load Balancing and TCP Connections

Tags: tcp, load-balancing

Apologies if this is a very naive question, but in the case of a TCP connection from a client to a backend server that is behind a load balancer, how does the load balancer know which server to serve the data to after the initial connection?

Thanks

Comment: it has a table of client port numbers, every TCP packet has source IP addr and port. So it knows which connection its for

Comment: Of course, that's obvious. Silly me! Every client will have a unique port + i.p. combination, even if the i.p. is the same. Thank you!